# Create Download link using PHP from the database

Tags: php, download

i wanna ask again,still have problems with my php code
i wanna ask how to create download link that looping from database, the file store in localhost in folder attach,anyone can help

my php code to show the attachment file store in database like this

```
<?php 
    if ($row['filename']==NULL)
    {echo "no attachment"; }
    else
    {echo $row['filename']; }
?>
```

from that generated i want to create a download link which is stored in my localhost

my attachment like it contains only 2 columns file name and file size

Regards
Wahyu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For making download link, you need to set appropriate [headers](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php).
For example

```
header('Content-type: application/pdf');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$filename);
```

To solve your problem, you can have a link like http://site.com/downloads.php?id=12456.
In the downloads.php page. you can check for the file name . and set the header in that page. Also its not necessary to have the content-type header.

Comment: CMIIW, from the php function header i've read that only for download pdf file type, but in my case i wanna create download link which is store in my db

Comment: i still not understand, so where i've that header and how to make a generate random link while looping ?

Comment: in the listing page you will create the links, while looping. This page will show the links to the download page, with the corresponding id for each file. In the download page you will set the header and it will out put the file.

Comment: ok thanks, i've tried, even hard to understand and tried, thanks for your answer

Answer (score 1):

Can you please explain your question more? Im not able to comment on questions yet, so I have to add an answer.

A general answer is:

In your database your store the filename of the file you want to be downloaded. Next, you generate a link with php and use the filename of the database.

After your edit/comment, something like this:

```
<?php 
    if ($row['filename']==NULL){
      print "no attachment"; 
    }else{ 
      printf("<a href='yourhost.com/folder/%s'",$row['filename']);
     }
?>
```

Comment: maybe you can show me which code to shown,,,sorry i'm beginner,

Comment: i wanna ask the php code to generate download link from the file location in database